# How to use empheq environment in TikZ nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, nodes, empheq

Using the `empheq` environment from the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package in a TikZ node is throwing errors for me (although it seems to be plotted correctly):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0)
        { % empheq is plotted but throws errors
            \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
                a = b
            \end{empheq}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Errors**

1. Bad math environment delimiter.
2. `\begin{equation*}` on input line ... ended by `\end{AmSequation*}`.

**What I already know**

From [Aligned equations inside of TikZ node.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/aligned-equations-inside-of-tikz-node) I have learned that `align` environment can be replaced by `aligned`:

```
    % --- align does not work ---
    \node at (0,0) {  \begin{align*} a = b \end{align*}  };

    % --- aligned does ---        
    \node at (0,0) {  $\begin{aligned} a = b \end{aligned}$  };
```

Please note that I depend on `empheq`'s functionality although the minimal working examples here do not reveal that.

Comment: I believe would be great to know why you're inserting equations in a TikZ node: if you wish to add arrows or other elements, there are simpler ways, i.e. `tikzmark`ing (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76507/13304) or using the `hf-tikz` package (which its main functionality is exactly formula highlighting). BTW: `align` has to be treated carefully: see [Numbering equations within dynblocks environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95410/13304).

Comment: For example to arbitrarily arrange formulas, text, arrows and pictures on beamer slides.

Comment: See: [Beamer: highlighting aligned math with overlay](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52598/beamer-highlighting-aligned-math-with-overlay/52600#52600), [Text below equation with hf-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133405/13304), [TikZ in itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77597/13304).

Comment: Your links are great but they are not solving my problem. I didn't want a proof for Tikz not to be needed. I use it for other purposes than `tikzmark` etc. are made for...

Comment: I see your point, that's why I was asking which is your purpose. Clearly, I misunderstood the question. People more skilled than me will provide you a good working solution even if I'm quite sure whatever you're doing can be done, easily from my view, in a tikzmark fashion.

Comment: No idea why it does this, `tikz` is an interesting beast. However, it works if you wrap the `empheq` in a `minipage` or `\parbox`. equivalently you could set the `text width` on the node.

Comment: Great! This works for me :-) I prefer the `text width` version, it seems to be the most elegant one. If you post this as an anwer I will accept it.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino First of all, thanks for your help! It is just the fact that I am now right into Tikz and I like all the ways to manipulate it and I am not too interested in going back to some second level solutions which are even new to me. I hope this is ok :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tikz` is an interesting beast. In this case `empheq` need to know the size of the area it is in. `tikz` nodes does not normally set such a size.

You can either put the `empheq` inside `minipage` or `\parbox`. or use the `text width` node option.